# Jquery - How to check which element was clicked with event target?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to check which element was clicked with event target?

```
e.on('click', function(){
    if(!$(e.target) == 'input'){
        //do something
    }
});
```

I've tried the following construction, but it seems not to be working, same as:

```
e.on('click', function(){
    if(!$(e.target).is('input')){
        //do something
    }
});
```

I just don't know is it possible for event target to check something like that.

Comment: Check this working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sh6u8/1/

Comment: The second example should work, it's just that you're not passing the event parameter to the function. It should be function(e) { ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to specify where is the element you click. Let's say we have this html:

**html**

```
<div></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("body").on("click", function(e) {
     if($(e.target).is("input")) {
           console.log(e.target);
     }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u82av/12/)

**Pure JS**

```
document.onclick = function(evt) {
    var evt=window.event || evt; // window.event for IE
    if (!evt.target) evt.target=evt.srcElement; // extend target property for IE
    alert(evt.target); // target is clicked
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u82av/10/)

Answer (score 2):

You should pass `event` like e . to check the clicked element has input or not use ***is*** selector in jquery

```
$("selector").on('click', function(e){
    if(!$(e.target).is('input')){
    //do something
}
});
```

**[is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)** selector in jquery

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely! Here is an example - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/h6DNa/

```
$('*').on('click', function(e) {
    if(!$(e.target).is('input')){
        console.log('clicked');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

use `document` as selector and add event `e` as parameter to function :

```
$(document).on('click', function(e){
    if(!$(e.target).is('input')){
       alert('yes');
    }
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QA2Ec/38/)**